# NSString to NSurl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

having trouble getting NSSTRING to convert to NSURL, item.image, holds the url for an image that im getting through xml

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.image];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSLog(@"string> %@ ", urlString);
NSLog(@"url> %@ ", url);

2011-06-23 11:18:49.610 Test[10126:207] string> http://www.harlemfur.com/images/Dog_Olive.jpg       
2011-06-23 11:18:49.611 Test[10126:207] url> (null)
```

also if i try :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.image];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath :urlString];

2011-06-23 11:22:08.063 Test[10199:207] string> http://www.harlemfur.com/images/Dog_Olive.jpg

2011-06-23 11:22:08.064 Test[10199:207] url> %0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://www.harlemfur.com/images/Dog_Olive.jpg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20 -- /
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The problem must be with item.image. What type is it exactly?

Comment: Do these lines appear in your code just like that? Directly one after another (constructing and logging)?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When making `URL` from `NSString`, don't forget to encode it first, so try this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.image];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**For IOS ≥ 9.0 use**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: thanks but this is the print out im getting :2011-06-23 11:41:34.796 Test[10609:207] string> 
                http://www.harlemfur.com/images/Dog_Olive.jpg
             
2011-06-23 11:41:34.797 Test[10609:207] url> %0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://www.harlemfur.com/images/Dog_Olive.jpg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20

Comment: Then you should check your item.image, make sure there is no hidden character. Checkout NSString documentation to see how to trim string.

Comment: you were right, i had extra spaces in my xml, thanks dude, works like a charm

Comment: Just a quick update, stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding is deprecated for IOS ≥ 9.0. You should use: stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]

Answer (score 2):

All is ok, if you want to get the URL to print in NSLog use this:

```
NSLog(@"url> %@ ", [url absoluteString]);
```

Comment: You *can* print objects directly in Objective-C. It calls the `description` method. Works fine with NSURL.

Answer (score 1):

`item.image` does not only contain the URL, but it starts with a newline and spaces. Remove those first and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: item.image!)
```