# Convert NSURL from String

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am just learning Objective-C from the couple of days and I am confused with NSURL. Here is my code

```
NSString *n = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://somedomain.com/api/x?q={\"order_by\":[{\"field\":\"t\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}"];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc ]initWithString:n];

NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

But when I trying to print an url value its null. 
It seems no problem when I try to init url without JSON parameter in url. 
Can I get some explanation where my problem is?

Comment: Have you googled about this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456605/nsstring-to-nsurl chek this out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *n = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://somedomain.com/api/x?q={\"order_by\":[{\"field\":\"t\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[n stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Comment: thanks it help me, i thought stringByAddingPrecentEscape is for percent character only.

Comment: Don't just throw code at us. Explain what went wrong in OPs code and what your code does different.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch ohk i will... thnx for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to compose a URL from strings is to use [NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html) helper class.

The reason for this seemingly elaborate approach is that each component of a URL (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)) requires slightly different percent encodings or possibly none.

The exact structure of the *query* component is not defined in RFC 3986, though. Usually, its an array of key/value pairs that will be escaped as described at w3.org: [x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm).  `NSURLComponents` provides a method to encode the query component as well.